# Javascript object got no access to its properties

Tags: javascript

I got an object with some information

```
function node(id, title, content, isPrivate, dateOfCreation) {
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.content = content;
  this.isPrivate = isPrivate;
  this.dateOfCreation = dateOfCreation;
  this.lastEdited = dateOfCreation;
}
```

and I can search for this object by its id

```
// this.nodes -> my array of objects
  this.getNodeById = function(nodeId){
    return $.grep(this.nodes, function(e){ return e.id === nodeId; });
  }
```

so this seems to work fine. When testing it I call a method first "test"

```
function test(){ // add a new object to the store at this.nodes
  store.addNode(new node("abcde12345", "title one", "content one", false, getCurrentDate()));
}
```

and the object gets added successfully. After that I call a method when initializing the website

```
function initEditor(nodeId){
test(); // call the testroutine
nodeId = "abcde12345"; // set the id
var n = store.getNodeById(nodeId); // search for this object in the store (datastore object)

var i = n.id;
var t = n.title;
var c = n.content;
var p = n.isPrivate;
var d = n.dateOfCreation;
var l = n.lastEdited;

debugger;
```

so my problem is, the variables i, t, c, p, d, l are null. And I don't get why because the variable "n" is correct. n stores the object but I can not access the properties of it.

For more information, this is my datastore "class"

```
var store = new dataStore();

function dataStore() {
  this.nodes = []; // the array of my objects

  this.getNodes = function() { // get all the objects
    return this.nodes;
  }

  this.addNode = function(entry) { // add a new object
    this.nodes.push(entry);
  }

  this.deleteNode = function(entry) { // delete an object from the array
    var index = this.nodes.indexOf(entry);
    if (index > -1)
      this.nodes.splice(index, 1);
  }

  this.getNodeById = function(nodeId){ // get an object by its id
    return $.grep(this.nodes, function(e){ return e.id === nodeId; });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is store in this code?

Comment: Is this store an array? Not able to see where it has been declared in your code

Comment: `$.grep()` returns an array

Comment: @Andreas ok, what can I do to get the object by its id then =?

Comment: How do you access an element of an array? ;)  (or use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `$.grep()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the variables is `undefined` because [`$.grep(array, function)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) returns an array with all elements that satisfied a filter function.

If the id will be unique you could change `.getNodeById()` to always return the first element of the result array:

```
this.getNodeById = function(nodeId){
  return $.grep(this.nodes, function(e){ return e.id === nodeId; })[0];
}
```

Or you could use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `$.grep()`:

```
this.getNodeById = function(nodeId){
  return this.nodes.find(function(e){ return e.id === nodeId; });
}
```

In both cases the result will be `undefined` if there is no node with the given id.